# VueJS - вывести данные из базы данных в реальном времени

Tags: веб-программирование, vue.js, api

Появилась следующая необходимость, а именно - вывод данных в "почти" реальном времени на сторону клиента с использованием VueJS. Имеется API, которое дает мне JSON строку, в JSON строке есть поле "статус" и этот "статус" мне необходимо обновлять как можно чаще. Каким способом можно обновлять данные с помощью Vue?

Comment: не совсем понятно при чем тут vue, `setInterval` для периодического опроса сервера должно быть достаточно

Comment: Где конкретно в компоненте Vue я должен написать setInterval? Axios запрос у меня стоит в mounted(), в data -> return я возвращаю ответ в шаблон. *не совсем понятно при чем тут vue* - действительно, совсем не при чем.

Comment: вы должны обернуть свой axios запрос к api обернуть в [`setInterval`](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval), `setInterval(() => axios.get('url').then(response => this.ВашаПеременная = response.data), 1000);` т.е. ваш запрос на api будет повторятся каждые 1000мс и обновляться на странице, вроде так

Comment: в идеале надо *запомнить* id который возвращает setInterval для того что бы при unmounted не слать запросы на сервер

Comment: @Bald огромное Вам спасибо! Вы сейчас мне очень помогли :) Довольно долго не мог разобраться с обновлением компонента, setInterval не сработал и пытался реализовать другими методами. Вся проблема заключалась в том, что я вызывал setInterval неправильно, а именно setInterval( axios query, ms ) вместо setInterval(() => axios query, ms ). В моем случаи у меня выходила ошибка промиса.